# numpy argmax not getting all values from generator expression

Tags: numpy, generator

The output of the following

```
import numpy as np
print(np.argmax([i for i in range(0, 10)]))
print(np.argmax(i for i in range(0, 10)))
```

is

```
9
0
```

Why does argmax reduce the generator expression only once?

Comment: What does ` np.array(I for I ...)` do?  Many numpy functions use that, or `np.asarray` to ensure they are working with a array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare these two expressions:

```
In [682]: np.asarray([i for i in range(3)])
Out[682]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [683]: np.asarray(i for i in range(3))
Out[683]: array(<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb367bb9c>, dtype=object)
```

`asarray` (or `array`) applied to a list produces an array with numbers.  The same thing applied to the generator produces a `dtype=object` array with 1 item, the generator itself. In fact its shape is `()` (0d).  You can recover this generator with `np.array(i for i in range(3))[()]`

`fromiter` can iterate a generator, but `array` only iterates on things like lists and tuples.

```
In [688]: np.fromiter((i for i in range(3)),int)
Out[688]: array([0, 1, 2])
```

And `argmax` depends on its input being an array.

Answer (score 2):

As i have don't have required reputation amount i am adding this an answer.

As suggested by @hpaulj, np.argmax calls asarray function in numeric.py. Here the developers have mentioned this in the code:

```
def asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):
    """Convert the input to an array.

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : array_like
        Input data, in any form that can be converted to an array.  This
        includes lists, lists of tuples, tuples, tuples of tuples, tuples
        of lists and ndarrays.
```

...

Hence your a doesn't match the requirements. Also why zero is returned for any input. This return value is from the function

```
result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
```

in fromnumeric.py which is called first. as for a generator object the code can't resolve the method, this function might return 0 as default

This was my research regarding the question